# How to restart another user's user service as root?

Tags: linux, systemd

So I have this scenario: `user-a` is running a systemd user service `user-a-service`. I'm root and I want to restart that user service. I can't find a way to do so. Basically I want this:

```
systemctl --user user-a restart user-a-service
```

Please not that this *not* a normal system service running with a specific non-root user but an actual user service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do this is by running `systemctl` as that user – and with the apropriate environment variables to allow it to find either the D-Bus user bus or the private systemd socket:

```
sudo -u user-a XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$(id -u user-a)" systemctl --user restart user-a-service
```

With newer systemd (v248), you can use `--machine` for loopback connections by specifying the special hostname `.host`; it will handle environment setup by calling PAM(login) automatically:

```
systemctl --machine user-a@.host --user restart user-a-service
```